# typescript @-annotation error

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I try to use the @-annotations in visualstudio in a typescript-file with angular 2.

But when I enter

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap, formDirectives} from "angular2/angular2";

@Component({

    selector: "tko-app"
})
@View({
    directives: [formDirectives],
    templateUrl: "mainapp.html"
});
class MainApp
.....
```

visualstudio 2015 shows me an error that @... is unexpected.
When remove the @ form the component there is no error and I get intellisense for Component and View...

Visual Studio Code is not complaining about that.

[image]

Comment: Try adding `/// <reference path="path_to/angular2.d.ts" />` at the beginning of your file

Answer (score 0):

> Visual Studio 2015 shows me an error that @... is unexpected

Install TypeScript 1.5 for VS 2015. Follow the tools link : http://www.typescriptlang.org/

Comment: Typescript 1.5.3 is already installed (checked the control panel). It automatically comes with VS 2015. I deleted the cache, repaired the installation of typescript but it still doesn't work.

Comment: its the fault of my resharper...i temporarily disabled it and the errors disappered. thanks Basarat